# Image and information div don't occupy the same height automatically

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have a image at left and at right some information. This information div at right have a orange border around. And I want that this information area occupies the same height of the image. So i created a div .details with display flex and align-items stretch. But its not working, the image and the information area dont occupy the same width. Do you know why?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/wjvwovy2/

html:

```
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="details">
      <div class="col-8 px-0" style="background-color: red">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x350"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 px-0">
        <div class="details-title d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Date</span>
          <h1 class="h5 font-weight-bold">Title</h1>
          <span class="details-title-subtitle font-size-sm font-weight-bold">Subtitle</span>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block details-title-subtitle-subtitle">Subtitle2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the layout you want? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/heLaheeL/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your fiddle it's just the closing bracket of `details-title` in the CSS which is missing:

https://jsfiddle.net/468p5rj7/2/

Comment: Thanks, actually i was using scss but in the fiddle i didnt select scss. In the fiddle is working fine, but in my example is not, the information div at right dont occupies the full height of the image, only half of the height +-. Do you know why?

Comment: Well, you didn't post a complete snippet (no CSS) in your question, so I just looked at the fiddle. Without CSS code it's difficult to say something.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have applied the visual styles in a descendant which is not a direct child of the `.details` element. There are several ways to fix this, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

A quick one is to apply `d-flex` class in `<div class="col-4 px-0">` and `flex-grow: 1` in `<div class="details-title d-flex flex-column align-items-start">`.

https://jsfiddle.net/todorito/32ukpemr/1/